# Forward delete character?

Tags: ruby

To dynamically delete a character from a string, you can use the `/b` character.

```
puts "Hello\b World!" #=> Hell World!
```

\b basically does the same thing as a backspace. Is there a character that emulates a forward delete?

Comment: Just curious - what will be a potential use case for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the execution of:

```
puts "Hello\b World!"
```

The `\b` doesn't delete the prior character. This is a common misconception since a backspace used on a keyboard will delete the previously typed character prior to the cursor on screen and from the keyboard input buffer. That behavior occurs because of how the keyboard input software of the operating system is designed.

In the case of the above `puts`, the `o` still exists in the string. What happens is that, when displayed, the backspace causes the `o` to be overwritten by the following space. This occurs because the `o` is display first, followed by the backspace (output cursor is backed up one character position), followed by the space, in sequence.

If you could have such a case where:

```
puts "Hello<del> World!"
```

would display `HelloWorld!`, then that would mean the output of the value of `<del>` would somehow cause the following output of space () to not occur. In other words, the `<del>` would have the function of, "whatever the next charter is that comes for the output, skip it". I don't believe such a control character exists in Windows or Linux output, although I suppose it would be possible to write an output driver that would have that behavior for some defined control character.

You might even be able to do something like this:

```
"Hello W<left-arrow><left-arrow><del><right-arrow>orld!"
```

Which would display `HelloWorld` if your terminal is set up to accept control characters that move the cursor left or right. But it still obviously isn't the same functionality as the "delete in the future" case.